# Unity game crashes at launch with Access Violation (0xc0000005) error

Tags: unity-game-engine

My unity game sometimes crashes at startup with a Access Violation (0xc0000005) error. It usually occurres only once or twice every 100 lauches, but it's been a real pain trying to understand why it happens.

I've noticed that every time the call in the stacktrace of output_log is related to the Stripify and the RtlUnicodeStringToInteger function.
The memory also always stops at 928 MB.

I'm using Unity version 5.4.2f2 and the game is running on Windows 10 home edition.

The error log is

```
Unity Player [version: Unity 5.4.2f2_b7e030c65c9b]

Game.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module Game.exe at 0023:005d3a42.

Error occurred at 2017-04-30_033456.
c:\game\Game.exe, run by user.
28% memory in use.
3986 MB physical memory [2861 MB free].
0 MB paging file [3548 MB free].
0 MB user address space [3606 MB free].
Read from location 00000028 caused an access violation.

Context:
EDI:    0x038b30c0  ESI: 0x00000000  EAX:   0x00000000
EBX:    0x00000001  ECX: 0x038fe510  EDX:   0x00000000
EIP:    0x005d3a42  EBP: 0x0193f62c  SegCs: 0x00000023
EFlags: 0x00210202  ESP: 0x0193f61c  SegSs: 0x0000002b

Bytes at CS:EIP:
39 42 28 74 04 4b 4e eb c8 33 c9 85 ff 74 08 8b 

Stack:
0x0193f61c: 00000000 00000000 038b50d0 00000000 .........P......
0x0193f62c: 0193f690 009a54ef 00000000 74c9e140 .....T......@..t
0x0193f63c: 00000001 00000004 038a7f10 04748c60 ............`.t.
0x0193f64c: 04748c60 00000000 00000000 00000000 `.t.............
0x0193f65c: 00000000 0051b79e 74c9e140 03fe1d00 ......Q.@..t....
0x0193f66c: 00000004 00000000 03ff8790 00000001 ................
0x0193f67c: 005b0120 04c2b670 00000000 038b50d0  .[.p........P..
0x0193f68c: 005d8167 0193f69c 0061a291 74c8ca50 g.].......a.P..t
0x0193f69c: 0193f6dc 006b182b 00000000 00000001 ....+.k.........
0x0193f6ac: 00000000 006b2079 00000000 0000000a ....y k.........
0x0193f6bc: 0003006c 00000200 00000000 018002ab l...............
0x0193f6cc: 0000a95f 000002ab 00000180 00000714 _...............
0x0193f6dc: 0193f814 006b40ae 00addbdb 00000000 .....@k.........
0x0193f6ec: 0172d000 038ab5e0 03c0003f 000003ff ..r.....?.......
0x0193f6fc: 00000001 00000020 0000002f 036d1c90 .... .../.....m.
0x0193f70c: 038ab5b0 7fffffff 0193f744 00afc580 ........D.......
0x0193f71c: 00000025 0000002f 0000000f 0000000f %.../...........
0x0193f72c: 7fffffff 00000000 0139f548 036d1598 ........H.9...m.
0x0193f73c: 0000000f 0193f700 0193f774 00af9240 ........t...@...
0x0193f74c: 036d1c90 01288b00 0000000f 0193f764 ..m...(.....d...
0x0193f75c: 7fffffff 038ab670 cd6305dd 0193f784 ....p.....c.....
0x0193f76c: 7760a043 00000026 0000002f 00000000 C.`w&.../.......
0x0193f77c: 038b4f10 01288b00 0193f7a4 00ad689a .O....(......h..
0x0193f78c: 00000017 0000001f 0193f6d0 616e614d ............Mana
0x0193f79c: 00646567 6c65746e 00000000 00000007 ged.ntel........
0x0193f7ac: 0000000f 0193f7bc 038a7a90 038a7ac8 .........z...z..
0x0193f7bc: 038a7ac8 0000000b 036eb040 65646900 .z......@.n..ide
0x0193f7cc: 646e6957 6c00776f 0193006c 00000000 Window.ll.......
0x0193f7dc: 0000000f 00000000 00000000 65726100 .............are
0x0193f7ec: 5748746e 0000444e 01ad2b5d 00000000 ntHWND..]+......
0x0193f7fc: 0000000f 00000000 036eb040 036eb080 ........@.n...n.
0x0193f80c: 00000000 00100801 0193f82c 00aae478 ........,...x...
0x0193f81c: 003f0000 00000000 01ad2b5f 0000000a ..?....._+......
0x0193f82c: 0193f8bc 00addb88 003f0000 00000000 ..........?.....
0x0193f83c: 01ad2b5f 0000000a ecb37872 00addbdb _+......rx......
0x0193f84c: 00addbdb 0172d000 00000044 01ad16a8 ......r.D.......
0x0193f85c: 01ad1688 01ad165a 00000000 00000000 ....Z...........
0x0193f86c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f87c: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x0193f88c: 0193f8b8 0193f8b8 00aef1c6 c0000005 ................
0x0193f89c: 00addbdb 00000000 0193f844 0193f1cc ........D.......
0x0193f8ac: 0193f908 00adf500 ec15bb76 00000000 ........v.......
0x0193f8bc: 0193f8d0 774a38f4 0172d000 774a38d0 .....8Jw..r..8Jw
0x0193f8cc: fa444d8f 0193f918 77635de3 0172d000 .MD......]cw..r.
0x0193f8dc: cd630bad 00000000 00000000 0172d000 ..c...........r.
0x0193f8ec: c0000005 76fff320 00000000 0193f1ac .... ..v........
0x0193f8fc: cd630bad 0193f8dc 0193f1ac 0193f920 ..c......... ...
0x0193f90c: 7764ed50 bb9cc6ad 00000000 0193f928 P.dw........(...
0x0193f91c: 77635dae ffffffff 7765b7e6 00000000 .]cw......ew....
0x0193f92c: 00000000 00addbdb 0172d000 00000000 ..........r.....
0x0193f93c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f94c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f95c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f96c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f97c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f98c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f99c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9ac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9bc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9cc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9dc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9ec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193f9fc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fa9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193faac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fabc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193facc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fadc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193faec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fafc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fb9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbbc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbcc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbdc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fbfc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fc9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fcac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fcbc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fccc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fcdc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fcec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fcfc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fd9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fdac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fdbc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fdcc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fddc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fdec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fdfc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fe9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193feac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193febc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fecc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fedc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193feec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fefc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff0c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff1c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff2c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff3c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff4c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff5c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff6c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff7c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ff9c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ffac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ffbc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ffcc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ffdc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193ffec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x0193fffc: 00000000                            ....

[Module List CUT]


== [end of error.log] ==
```

and the output_log is

```
Initialize engine version: 5.4.2f2 (b7e030c65c9b)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.0]
    Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics (ID=0xf31)
    Vendor:   Intel
    VRAM:     928 MB
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\SampleClassLibrary.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\SampleClassLibrary.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\BestHTTP.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\BestHTTP.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.185 seconds
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\System.dll (this message is harmless)
<RI> Initializing input.
XInput1_3.dll not found. Trying XInput9_1_0.dll instead...
<RI> Input initialized.
desktop: 1366x768 60Hz; virtual: 1366x768 at 0,0
<RI> Initialized touch support.
UnloadTime: 1.738755 ms
Thread done...

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

Waiting for client...

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
device:039 lastUpdate=1467983427

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

SEND keepAlive!

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

Platform assembly: c:\game\Game_Data\Managed\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
Configuration keepAlive:True

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;C:\Windows\system32;c:\game;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 530, UserName: 'user'
OS-Version: 10.0.10586 () 0x300-0x1
c:\game\Game.exe:Game.exe (003F0000), size: 18583552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'c:\game\Game.exe', fileVersion: 5.4.2.57392
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (775D0000), size: 1552384 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.306
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL:KERNEL32.DLL (77490000), size: 917504 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (76EC0000), size: 1564672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (746F0000), size: 1372160 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.420
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll (74C70000), size: 1339392 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.306
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (748F0000), size: 503808 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.63
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll (743C0000), size: 778240 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (770A0000), size: 278528 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (74840000), size: 708608 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.306
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll:SspiCli.dll (74300000), size: 122880 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll:CRYPTBASE.dll (742F0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll:bcryptPrimitives.dll (77570000), size: 360448 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.420
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (76500000), size: 389120 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.420
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll:ole32.dll (74480000), size: 962560 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll:combase.dll (74DC0000), size: 1822720 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.103
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (770F0000), size: 282624 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (75050000), size: 20963328 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll:cfgmgr32.dll (74F80000), size: 225280 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll:windows.storage.dll (76570000), size: 5218304 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll:kernel.appcore.dll (76560000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll:shcore.dll (74320000), size: 577536 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll:powrprof.dll (77350000), size: 278528 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll:profapi.dll (77480000), size: 61440 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (772B0000), size: 598016 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (76A70000), size: 176128 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IMM32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (73690000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (74210000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (71020000), size: 917504 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (74050000), size: 147456 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll:DNSAPI.dll (70F90000), size: 540672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.212
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (764F0000), size: 28672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL:IPHLPAPI.DLL (740A0000), size: 192512 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (70EF0000), size: 634880 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.420
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (70EC0000), size: 151552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll:DDRAW.dll (70DD0000), size: 974848 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll:WINMMBASE.dll (737B0000), size: 143360 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll:DCIMAN32.dll (73540000), size: 28672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.3
C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (70D50000), size: 479232 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\tiptsf.dll:tiptsf.dll (734C0000), size: 512000 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\tiptsf.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
c:\game\Game_Data\Mono\mono.dll:mono.dll (10000000), size: 2293760 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'c:\game\Game_Data\Mono\mono.dll', fileVersion: 1.0.0.1
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL:PSAPI.DLL (76EB0000), size: 24576 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll:MSWSOCK.dll (73740000), size: 323584 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.420
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (74B50000), size: 1175552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.71
C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (70B40000), size: 118784 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll:d3d11.dll (71480000), size: 2203648 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll:dxgi.dll (71360000), size: 532480 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igd10iumd32.dll:igd10iumd32.dll (70000000), size: 11767808 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igd10iumd32.dll', fileVersion: 10.18.10.4358
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll:bcrypt.dll (73670000), size: 110592 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll:ncrypt.dll (6FFE0000), size: 131072 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll:NTASN1.dll (6FFB0000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc32.dll:igdusc32.dll (6FC30000), size: 3645440 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc32.dll', fileVersion: 10.18.10.4358
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll:clbcatq.dll (74FC0000), size: 540672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll', fileVersion: 2001.12.10941.16384
C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll:MMDevApi.dll (71420000), size: 348160 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll:PROPSYS.dll (71180000), size: 1355776 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\System32\DEVOBJ.dll:DEVOBJ.dll (742C0000), size: 139264 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\System32\DEVOBJ.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wdmaud.drv:wdmaud.drv (6FBF0000), size: 229376 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wdmaud.drv', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ksuser.dll:ksuser.dll (6FBE0000), size: 28672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ksuser.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll:AVRT.dll (6FBD0000), size: 36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (6FB60000), size: 425984 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.71
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll:wintypes.dll (73200000), size: 819200 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.103
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msacm32.drv:msacm32.drv (6FB50000), size: 36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msacm32.drv', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll:MSACM32.dll (6FB30000), size: 98304 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\midimap.dll:midimap.dll (6FB20000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\midimap.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\xinput9_1_0.dll:xinput9_1_0.dll (6F9C0000), size: 28672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\xinput9_1_0.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\uiautomationcore.dll:uiautomationcore.dll (6F8A0000), size: 1163264 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\uiautomationcore.dll', fileVersion: 7.2.10586.212
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll:USERENV.dll (74080000), size: 102400 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll:sxs.dll (74230000), size: 528384 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll:OLEACC.dll (6F7F0000), size: 344064 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll', fileVersion: 7.2.10586.212
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\twinapi.dll:twinapi.dll (6F750000), size: 602112 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\twinapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\twinapi.appcore.dll:twinapi.appcore.dll (732D0000), size: 843776 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\twinapi.appcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.494
c:\game\Game_Data\Plugins\sqlite3.dll:sqlite3.dll (60900000), size: 581632 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'c:\game\Game_Data\Plugins\sqlite3.dll'
C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll:rasadhlp.dll (70B60000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.71
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (740D0000), size: 1306624 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.10586.0

========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x005D3A42 (Game) Stripify
0x009A54EF (Game) RegisterModule_IMGUI
0x0061A291 (Game) RectT<int>::Contains
0x006B182B (Game) Append
0x006B40AE (Game) PlayerWinMain
0x00AAE478 (Game) RemapPPtrTransfer::TransferTypeless
0x00ADDB88 (Game) RemapPPtrTransfer::TransferTypeless
0x774A38F4 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x77635DE3 (ntdll) RtlUnicodeStringToInteger

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========

**** Crash! ****
```

Comment: so what is Stripify doing?

Comment: I never call the Stripify function from the script code (which is in C#) so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Do you have Citrix Receiver or Citrix Workspace installed?